# SQL JOIN Questions and Answers with NULL missing answers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `questions` that holds questions and a table `answers` that holds answers to the questions. Note: There may not be an answer for every question. I also have a column in `answers` that contains the person_id (the person who answered the question).

I need to do a JOIN query to get all the questions, and an answer for the question, if applicable, for a particular person.

```
select question.text, answers.answer, answer.id from question
left outer join answers
on question.id = answers.question_id
where answers.person_id = 175
```

I'm expecting null as the answer if there is no answer for a particular question, but with my current query I don't get the question or the answer if there is no answer.

Comment: I'd like to understand this better - you expect to always get a list of all questions, right? And answer(s) if existing... and the solution below works that way, but yours does not? I'm not fully convinced how a filtering on the right table can have an impact on entries of the left one showing up or not in this case.
One other comment, I might be wrong, but I think MySQL doesn't really have an 'outer' join implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `left join`, but the `where` condition needs to be in the `on` clause:

```
select q.text, a.answer, a.id
from question q left outer join
     answers a
     on q.id = a.question_id and a.person_id = 175;
```

Comment: That's it - thank you! I knew I was missing something.